# Unhandled Rejection Cannot read property 'map' of undefined

Tags: node.js, reactjs, mern

```
0: {id: "rate_e2a0f571f06d4d99820a5ab3bc71517d", object: "Rate", created_at: "2020-12-01T18:05:30Z", updated_at: "2020-12-01T18:05:30Z", mode: "test", …}
1: {id: "rate_3f53494bb37a463da234e9602ef948cf", object: "Rate", created_at: "2020-12-01T18:05:30Z", updated_at: "2020-12-01T18:05:30Z", mode: "test", …}
2: {id: "rate_352c17339f0f495ebab083a219a2cad1", object: "Rate", created_at: "2020-12-01T18:05:30Z", updated_at: "2020-12-01T18:05:30Z", mode: "test", …}
3: {id: "rate_da9cab9fa50143389d3fbf84989b864d", object: "Rate", created_at: "2020-12-01T18:05:30Z", updated_at: "2020-12-01T18:05:30Z", mode: "test", …}
4: {id: "rate_faaf9539385e4caabf2da67ab64716d1", object: "Rate", created_at: "2020-12-01T18:05:30Z", updated_at: "2020-12-01T18:05:30Z", mode: "test", …}
5: {id: "rate_3d12c0d9fa8645b9a62258827340cecd", object: "Rate", created_at: "2020-12-01T18:05:30Z", updated_at: "2020-12-01T18:05:30Z", mode: "test", …}
6: {id: "rate_18a92d09612e4afa844c6c9ec1d18c00", object: "Rate", created_at: "2020-12-01T18:05:30Z", updated_at: "2020-12-01T18:05:30Z", mode: "test", …}
7: {id: "rate_d352e82f333a4998bc01d3c1ff98adfa", object: "Rate", created_at: "2020-12-01T18:05:30Z", updated_at: "2020-12-01T18:05:30Z", mode: "test", …}
8: {id: "rate_a2c1d21a9b0f46e790a46f0788b9ea79", object: "Rate", created_at: "2020-12-01T18:05:30Z", updated_at: "2020-12-01T18:05:30Z", mode: "test", …}
9: {id: "rate_3c249349f10a4cb6b791e9cb78c9d1a4", object: "Rate", created_at: "2020-12-01T18:05:30Z", updated_at: "2020-12-01T18:05:30Z", mode: "test", …}
10: {id: "rate_a99575a793d64ad98c14052d150a256e", object: "Rate", created_at: "2020-12-01T18:05:30Z", updated_at: "2020-12-01T18:05:30Z", mode: "test", …}
11: {id: "rate_dfc8440294964402939e12a2c8e20f1c", object: "Rate", created_at: "2020-12-01T18:05:30Z", updated_at: "2020-12-01T18:05:30Z", mode: "test", …}
12: {id: "rate_aeb5969167a1496a909ed711703e4f69", object: "Rate", created_at: "2020-12-01T18:05:30Z", updated_at: "2020-12-01T18:05:30Z", mode: "test", …}
13: {id: "rate_d1586dfd20e24af59ea48a1a2fd34a63", object: "Rate", created_at: "2020-12-01T18:05:30Z", updated_at: "2020-12-01T18:05:30Z", mode: "test", …}
14: {id: "rate_a6d206a0c40245a6a87c12b3c48e9d21", object: "Rate", created_at: "2020-12-01T18:05:30Z", updated_at: "2020-12-01T18:05:30Z", mode: "test", …}
15: {id: "rate_da3e73cef3b242248535ac9e8a6992ff", object: "Rate", created_at: "2020-12-01T18:05:30Z", updated_at: "2020-12-01T18:05:30Z", mode: "test", …}
16: {id: "rate_faf6a896018840a59533b165108fc6c2", object: "Rate", created_at: "2020-12-01T18:05:30Z", updated_at: "2020-12-01T18:05:30Z", mode: "test", …}
17: {id: "rate_07c4f76b46f94527a2ca9077146fe1e6", object: "Rate", created_at: "2020-12-01T18:05:30Z", updated_at: "2020-12-01T18:05:30Z", mode: "test", …}
18: {id: "rate_0d45a43e11bb47fab7e5fdba93acd09c", object: "Rate", created_at: "2020-12-01T18:05:30Z", updated_at: "2020-12-01T18:05:30Z", mode: "test", …}
19: {id: "rate_f8cbad84e2cd4d298a9d3ca1e75ecb77", object: "Rate", created_at: "2020-12-01T18:05:30Z", updated_at: "2020-12-01T18:05:30Z", mode: "test", …}
20: {id: "rate_26105802e7304913b5d3fbe8673c1735", object: "Rate", created_at: "2020-12-01T18:05:30Z", updated_at: "2020-12-01T18:05:30Z", mode: "test", …}
21: {id: "rate_4cc4043d3ebb4d6db6689417c464cd5a", object: "Rate", created_at: "2020-12-01T18:05:30Z", updated_at: "2020-12-01T18:05:30Z", mode: "test", …}
22: {id: "rate_ede9271a3fd94727916345a5550d1a8d", object: "Rate", created_at: "2020-12-01T18:05:30Z", updated_at: "2020-12-01T18:05:30Z", mode: "test", …}
23: {id: "rate_44a46f2d9ed04bd39f47d4d663bf6bbc", object: "Rate", created_at: "2020-12-01T18:05:30Z", updated_at: "2020-12-01T18:05:30Z", mode: "test", …}
24: {id: "rate_42cca61009cd4b28aa7f685002c7aa60", object: "Rate", created_at: "2020-12-01T18:05:30Z", updated_at: "2020-12-01T18:05:30Z", mode: "test", …}
length: 25
__proto__: Array(0)
```

My Code

```
const Rates = ({props})=>{
   console.log(props)
             return(
               
             <div>
               <ul>
               {
                // props.forEach(element => {
                //   console.log(element)
                // }),
                props.map( (jsondetail , index )=> {
                  
                  return ( <li key = {index} value ={jsondetail.rate}>{jsondetail.service}</li>)
                })
               }
               </ul>
               </div> 
             )
```

Comment: How are you passing props in rates? Can you share that code too?

Comment: you're destructuring props in the arguments. What you need is (props) instead of ({props})  passed in Rates. Unless you're passing a prop called "props" like <Rates props={...data} .../>

Comment: use a logical && operator, like this: Array.isArray(props) && props.length > 0 && props.map.... your code